# Authentication view doesn't recognize html template

Tags: django, django-views

I'm using authentication views in my project https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views 
`path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),` in my urls 
My issue is when it comes to the [PasswordChangeView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordChangeView) the `accounts/password_change` url shows the django adminstration page instead of the template I have under `posts\templates\registration\password_change_form.html`
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you set your `template_name` in **urls.py**?

> Example that works in my project.

```
from django.urls import path, reverse_lazy
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views



app_name='account'

urlpatterns = [

<...>

    # -- Change Password
    path('change_password/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(
        template_name='password/password_change.html',
        success_url=reverse_lazy('account:password_change_done')), 
        name='password_change'),

<...>
]
```

in your case set it to `template_name='registration\password_change_form.html'`

Comment: Well this works but it didn't resolve the main issue

Comment: @Saadat Esmaeily you should provide more Information. As far as i understand ,your Problem was: how to use your own template for `password_change` and not the default.